# Variables in Kubernetes ConfigMaps

Tags: variables, kubernetes, configmap

I'm currently working with some configmaps and I've noticed, that there are some documents in the configmap having redundant values/ referencing the same value e.g.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
  labels:
    app: my-app
data:
  some_file: |-
     ...
     foo1=bar
     ...
  some_other_file: |-
     ...
     foo2=bar
     ...
```

Is it somehow possible, to use a variable instead of writing `bar` two times?
This way I wouldn't have to search every config file if `bar` changes at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

If the problems gets worse, you can always start using [kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) or [Helm](https://helm.sh/), which allow you to create templates for your Kubernetes manifests, and use variables on those templates.